# Database Design: Form with many fields

Tags: database-design

I want to know if there are any recommendations/best practices in terms of **naming the fields** which will store values of a form with ~20-30 fields.

The form may change, infrequently (maybe in 4-8 years, or less).

The majority of the group seems to think that Box001,Box002,..,Box030 is the solution which needs to be adopted.

I feel strongly that the names of the fields need semantically descriptive of what the "box" represents. For mainly two reasons: frame shifting in case of removal/addition and it will be easier to refer to these fields.

We gave up the option of serializing the form fields mainly because reports may be generated on the data in the future.

Given that I am facing an apposing majority in my group:

1. Are there any best practices for storing this sort of data?
2. Is there any compelling argument or am I simply wrong in my stance?

Answer (score 0):

If this structure is rather static, so doesn't change a lot, I hardly see why you would make it generic. I'm personally in favor of naming your columns correctly, showing intend (descriptive as you say), but also typing and constraining it correctly. It will also avoid your data to become inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I do feel the same as you when designing  database, that the table names and fields should be semantically descriptive.

however, if there is a requirement for the front end to change over time, even you name the fields as Box001, Box002, this will confuse more after number of iteration, specially if the developer is new.

It would be worth thinking of creating a intermediate table that maps the front end to the back end.

Say for example you have a textbox in the form called "Address" and you have a field in your db called Street Name. so you create a table that maps the Address to Street Name, so in the future, "Address" suddenly become "Address Line 1", you only have to update the map. This way you can maintain the db fields descriptive.